# AG Grid v23 doesn't allowed export excel with multiple header

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Can you help me.
AG Grid v23 doesn't allowed export excel with multiple header.

I have a table two headers : one is group month and other one is normal header.

Thank you

I would like get some solution. Please notice that i have AG Grid v23.2.0